# Improving samples from a distribution

Tags: sampling, resampling, importance-sampling

I have a long-standing problem regarding generating samples from a desired distribution, $p(x)$. I know the analytic form of $p(x)$.

I have a mechanism that *should* draw samples from $p(x)$, and does so in a rather complicated way. This mechanism must be used to generate the "initial" samples from the distribution (so I mean to say I am not looking to use some other "proposal" distribution, $f(x)$, say, to produce samples in the style of the accept / reject algorithm) because the samples have some other desirable properties when produced this way.

However, the mechanism appears to introduce a certain (difficult to quantify) error in the samples that are produced. It seems there is a statistical error inherent in the method used to produce these samples so they only *approximate* the desired  distribution. I am looking for a way to improve these initial samples: to find an algorithm like the accept / reject method, say, which will allow me to decide to resample some of the initial samples and accept others in such a way that the final sample better follows $p(x)$.

The important point is that I do **not** know the distribution that the initial samples are ending up resembling -- let's call in $p'(x)$. I know that $p'(x) \approx p(x)$ in that a histogram of the samples fits rather well to $p(x)$, but not perfectly. So the only reliable information I have for each of the initial samples, $x$, is the value $p(x)$.

**Can I form a criterion for accepting these samples, based upon $p(x)$, in such a way that the accepted values follow $p(x)$ better than before?**

Comment: The only easy fix I can think of is to run a few MCMC steps tuned to $p(\cdot)$ after an initial simulatin from $p^\prime(\cdot)$.

Comment: I would like to do this, but isn't that difficult without knowing $p'(\cdot)$? The transition probability from $x \rightarrow x'$ isn't symmetric if the new points are drawn from $p'$.... Or does this not matter?

Comment: I was rather suggesting using a manageable transition $q(x^\prime|x)$, using $p^\prime(\cdot)$ only as the starting distribution. If it is close to $p(\cdot)$, a few steps of a random walk Metropolis should suffice.

Comment: I see - I can try to implement that. I was also wondering whether it's possible to do some form of resampling (like a Jackknife or bootstrap analysis) using knowledge of the desired distribution to improve estimations with the generated sample or maybe to give some extra weights to certain samples over others?

Comment: You could use an accept-reject step (in addition to your MCMC steps) to guarantee that your samples follow $p(x)$. You can find an example of this at -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm#Intuition step 2 will show you an example. This step will guarantee asymptotic correctness with $p'(x)$ and $p(x)$!